# How do get North, East, South, or West bounds from Cesium map?

Tags: cesium

I see that there is an option that allows for one to set the view if you provide the coordinates for these bounds, but nowhere in the documentation do I see anything pertaining to retrieving these values as defined by the canvas container / rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

The current view bounds can be calculated by [`Camera.computeViewRectangle`](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/Camera.html#computeViewRectangle).  Note that the results here can be approximate, due to the complexity of a perspective 3D view of the globe.

For details on that, see [Cesium 3D - Determining the Map Scale of the viewed Globe](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129903/cesium-3d-determining-the-map-scale-of-the-viewed-globe/144496#144496).